# Law of total variance on conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation, variance

Let's take 3 random variables $X,Y,Z$ on the same probability space (or associated with the same experiment), then the law of total variance states that:

$$ V[X] = V[E[X|Z]] + E[V[X|Z]]  $$

Then what if I want to apply the law of total variance on the following conditional variance: $V[X|Y]$? The goal is to decompose this conditional variance further. Would this result in something like
$$ V[X|Y] = V[E[X|Z|Y]] + E[V[X|Z|Y]]  $$
or maybe
$$ V[X|Y] = V[E[X|Z,Y]|Y] + E[V[X|Z,Y]|Y]  $$

Thanks a lot for any help or suggestions.

Comment: $V\big[E[X\mid Z\mid Y]\big] + E\big[V[X\mid Z\mid Y]\big]$ does not make much sense notationally.  $V[X\mid Y] = V\big[E[X\mid Z,Y]\mid Y\big] + E\big[V[X\mid Z,Y]\mid Y\big]$ does.

Comment: @Henry, thanks! Indeed, I was wondering the same while looking at the notation... So one should write $E[X|Z,Y]$ to say something like "X knowing Z, knowing Y" (its an "and" I am looking for ?)

Comment: If you are conditioning $X$ on knowing $Z$ and on knowing $Y$ then you are conditioning on knowing both of them together rather than on one after the other.

Comment: @Henry, yes indeed, thanks for the clarification. Can I not write then: $V[X|Y]=V[E[X|Z]|Y]+E[V[X|Z]|Y]$? Is this the same as $V[X|Y]=V[E[X|Z,Y]|Y]+E[V[X|Z,Y]|Y]$

Comment: No - see my answer for a simple counterexample with $Y$ and $Z$ independent and $X=Y+Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V\big[E[X\mid Z\mid Y]\big] + E\big[V[X\mid Z\mid Y]\big]$ does not make much sense notationally.

$V\big[E[X\mid Z]\mid Y\big] + E\big[V[X\mid Z]\mid Y\big]$ makes sense notationally but does not always give $V[X\mid Y]$.

$V[X\mid Y] = V\big[E[X\mid Z,Y]\mid Y\big] + E\big[V[X\mid Z,Y]\mid Y\big]$ both makes sense and is what you want.

To illustrate the distinction consider the example where  $Y$ and $Z$ are i.i.d. Bernouilli$(\frac12)$, i.e. each independently $0$ or $1$ with equal probability and mean $\frac12$, and $X=Y+Z$:

- You can find $V[X\mid Y]=V[Z]=\frac14$ since $Y$ and $Z$ are independent here.
- $E[X \mid Z] =\frac12+Z$ and so $V\big[E[X\mid Z]\mid Y\big]=V\big[\frac12\mid Y\big]+V\big[Z\mid Y\big]=0+\frac14$, while $V[X \mid Z] =V[Y]=\frac14$  and so $E\big[V[X\mid Z]\mid Y\big]=\frac14$, giving $V\big[E[X\mid Z]\mid Y\big] + E\big[V[X\mid Z]\mid Y\big] = \frac12$, which is not $V[X\mid Y]$.
- $E[X\mid Z,Y]=Y+Z$ and so $V\big[E[X\mid Z,Y]\mid Y\big]=V\big[Y\mid Y\big]+V\big[Z\mid Y\big]=0+\frac14$ again, while $V[X \mid Z,Y] =0$ *(here, if you know $Z$ and $Y$ then you know $X$ exactly)* and so $E\big[V[X\mid Z,Y]\mid Y\big]=0$, giving $V\big[E[X\mid Z,Y]\mid Y\big] + E\big[V[X\mid Z,Y]\mid Y\big] = \frac14$, as desired.

Comment: Henry: Thanks a lot for your answer and clear explanations. However, in your last line did you mean: $ V[E[X∣Z,Y]∣Y]+E[V[X∣Z,Y]∣Y] $ instead of $V[E[X∣Z]∣Y]+E[V[X∣Z]∣Y]$ ?

Comment: @BMBE Yes - thank you - edited