# Law of total variance on function of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, variance

Let's take the following random variables $X,Y,Z_1,...,Z_K$, on the same probability space (or associated with the same experiment), where we know that
$$ Y = \sum_{k=1}^K\beta_kZ_k$$

Let's say I am interested in computing the conditional variance of $X$ knowing $Y$, similarly as in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879172/law-of-total-variance-on-conditional-expectation?rq=1). Applying the law of total variance, we get:

$$ V[X|Y]=V[E[X|Z_1,...,Z_K,Y]|Y]+E[V[X|Z_1,...,Z_K,Y]|Y] $$

In this special case, since when we know $Z_1,...,Z_K$, we also know $Y$, can we reduce the law of total variance to:

$$ V[X|Y]=V[E[X|Z_1,...,Z_K]|Y]+E[V[X|Z_1,...,Z_K]|Y] $$

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: It does not look like you have any special structure other than $X$ and $Y$ are general random variables (the $Z_i$ values do not seem helpful here, perhaps $Z_1=Y, Z_i=0 \quad \forall i \neq 1$). So you cannot say much more than using  $E[X|Y]$ and $E[X^2|Y]$ (which are not computable unless more info is given).

Comment: Michael: Thanks for your comment. I will provide more details, but I wanted to keep this problematization as general as possible, it will make things more challenging.

Comment: Michael: After thinking about it, I do not think it is necessary to give further details or to know the exact distribution of the presented random variables to answer the question. I just need to specify that they are linked, somehow, by being on the same probability space. Otherwise, the conditioning becomes redundant. The question here is about whether we can simplify the conditioning inside the inner expectation $E[X|Z_1,...,Z_K,Y] = E[X|Z_1,...,Z_K]$.

Comment: Michael: After some thoughts, the answer for me is "yes", as once you know $Z_1,...,Z_K$, you also know any function of these random variables, so knowing $Y$ becomes redundant.